# How to calculate correct position offsets for rotated image?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, math

I am trying to create a small gauge control, sort of like a speedometer in a car, except that it only spans 180 degrees.

To render the control I am using two image files. The first is simply the background for the gauge and shows a half-circle that goes from green at 0 degrees to red at 180 degrees. The second image is a vertical arrow of about the same height as the radius of the half-circle and slightly less that the height of the background image.

I am using the following markup to render the control:

```
<div class="gauge" id="@Model.ClientID">
    <img class="gauge" alt="" src="@Url.Content( "~/images/icons/gauge-bg.png" )" />
    <img class="arrow" alt="" src="@Url.Content( "~/images/icons/gauge-arrow.png" )" />
</div>
```

The images are positioned relatively inside the div in order to allow them to overlap. The background image is 120x63 pixels and the arrow image is 12x58 pixels (WxH), but that can be adjusted if it makes solving the problem easier. The arrow image points straight up before any rotation is applied.

I have a percentage (from 0 to 100) that I translate into an angle of rotation for the arrow image (from -90 to 90), which looks like this:

```
// input value for the offset calculations (see below)
public double ArrowRotationDegrees 
{
    // 0 for 0%, 90 for 50% and 180 for 100%
    get { return 180.0 * Percent / 100; }
}

// input value for the jquery rotate plugin as our base arrow points vertically up
public double ArrowRotationDegreesRelative // -90 for 0%, 0 for 50% and 90 for 100%
{
    // -90 for 0%, 0 for 50% and 90 for 100%
    get { return ArrowRotationDegrees - 90; }
}
```

To perform the rotation I'm using [jquery-rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/), which appears to always rotate around the center of the image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var arrow = $('#@Model.ClientID').find('img.arrow');
        arrow.rotate(@Model.ArrowRotationDegreesRelative);
        arrow.css({left: @Model.ArrowLeftShiftPixels, top: @Model.ArrowTopShiftPixels});
    });
</script>
```

But how do I calculate the correct offsets for re-positioning the rotated image, such that the arrow always points from the exact center bottom of the background image?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Based on the answer from Eric J. I was able to adjust my code and get a working result without changing the markup:

```
public int ArrowLeftShiftPixels // used to position rotated image correctly horizontally
{
    // default offset (no rotation) is left:55
    get { return 55 - GetArrowLeftShift( ArrowRotationDegrees ); }
}

public int ArrowTopShiftPixels // used to position rotated image correctly vertically
{
    // default offset (no rotation) is top:5
    // formula output is shifted (max appears where min should be); add 29 to reverse this effect
    get { return 34 - GetArrowTopShift( ArrowRotationDegrees ); }
}

public int GetArrowLeftShift( double degrees )
{
    var result = (58.0 / 2) * Math.Cos( degrees * Math.PI / 180 );
    return (int) Math.Round( result, 0 );
}

public int GetArrowTopShift( double degrees )
{
    var result = (58.0 / 2) * Math.Sin( degrees * Math.PI / 180 );
    return (int) Math.Round( result, 0 );
}
```

Thanks for all the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked at the specific numbers of your problem in detail (is the arrow rooted on the bottom pointed up or vice-versa?), but you will probably find that the tips of the arrow shift left or right of the center of the image by `(half it's length) * cos(Angle)`, while they shift up or down by `(half it's length) * sin (Angle)`.  Be sure when specifying the angle that you use radians or degrees as appropriate to the trig library you use to calculate the sin and cos.

If you calculate the [sin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [cos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) server-side in C#, use radians.

[Here's an explanation](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm) of how to rotate for arbitrary angles (matches what I just explained, but the diagrams may help).  Note in your case, the initial angle is 0, so the initial formulas are

> x = 0 (since cos(0) = 0)
>   y = r (since r * sin(0) = r)

Comment: At first I couldn't make this work, until I made a table of working/expected output values and compared this with the calculation results. The TopShift value is somehow shifted (the min values appear where the max values were expected), but it was easy to compensate for once you spotted the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a div that is roughly twice the size of the image, in both dimensions.  Then you would position your image inside that div, absolutely, so the pivot point of the image (the bottom of the arrow) is at the divs half hight and width.  You would then translate the div into the correct area (so the images pivotal point is in the correct area), then perform the rotation on the div.

EDIT: Here's a jsfiddle to explain it
http://jsfiddle.net/pVpE7/

Comment: I tried adding a wrapper div, but I weren't able to come up with anything that worked, so I went back to calculating the offsets. It looks like it should have worked if I had done things right though, so +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6bGpY/). Explanation:

The rotate plugin does not let you specify the anchor point -- it always rotates around the center. I've simply doubled the size of the arrow so that it stretches across the width of the gauge. Rotating this arrow gives you the desired effect. Minor tweaks to CSS added to keep the overflowing portion of the arrow in control.

Comment: I also looked at this and you obviously have something working (+1), but I was not able to translate this into something that worked for me.